# TabBarController icon not showing until clicked - No Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift

Ive added a number of tabs to a tabbar controller by

```
private func setupViewControllers() {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let layout2 = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let controllers = [
            VLCAudioViewController(services: services),
            VLCDJViewController(collectionViewLayout: layout),            
            VLCUserViewController(collectionViewLayout: layout2)
        ]

        tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers.map { UINavigationController(rootViewController: $0) }
    }
```

And what happens is the last tab doesnt show its icon until clicked.

before click

[image]

after click

[image]

It seems to be because im adding a second collectionViewLayout as if i change the type it appears.

Comment: Where are you set image for tabbar item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see your above code. I guest you set tabbar item icon in viewDidLoad of these ViewController. 
Please set icon for tabbar item when setup viewControllers of tabbarController

UPDATE: Try like

```
private func setupViewControllers() {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let layout2 = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let vlcUserVC = VLCUserViewController(collectionViewLayout: layout2)
        // Set tabbar item
        vlcUserVC.tabbarItem = UITabBarItem.init(title: "User", image: UIImage(named: "user-icon"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "user-selected"))
        let controllers = [
            VLCAudioViewController(services: services),
            VLCDJViewController(collectionViewLayout: layout),            
            vlcUserVC
        ]

        tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers.map { UINavigationController(rootViewController: $0) }
    }
```

Comment: How? Im new to ios development. I find no mention of "VLCUserViewController" anywhere else but the code i posted and its view controller.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks